# Loop Through Table Rows Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, beautifulsoup, tablerow

I need help looping through table rows and putting them into a list.  On this website, there are three tables, each with different statistics - http://www.fangraphs.com/statsplits.aspx?playerid=15640&position=OF&season=0&split=0.4

For instance, these three tables have rows for 2016, 2017, and a total row.  I would like the following:

A list of the following -->table 1 - row 1, table 2 - row 1, table 3 - row 1
A second list of the following -->table 1 - row 2, table 2 - row 2, table 3 - row 2
A third list: -->table 1 - row 3, table 2 - row 3, table 3 - row 3

I know I obviously need to create lists, and need to use the append function; however, I am not sure how to get it to loop through just the first row of each table, then the second row of each table, and etc through each row of the table (the number of rows will vary in each instance - this one just happens to have 3).

Any help is greatly appreciated.  The code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

idList2 = ['15640', '9256']
splitList=[0.4,0.2,0.3,0.4]
for id in idList2:
    pos = 'OF'
    for split in splitList:
        url = 'http://www.fangraphs.com/statsplits.aspx?playerid=' + 
            str(id) + '&position=' + str(pos) + '&season=0&split=' + 
            str(split) + ''
        r = requests.get(url)

        for season in range(1,4):
            print(season)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
            tableStats = soup.find("table", {"id" :  "SeasonSplits1_dgSeason" + str(season) + "_ctl00"})
            soup.findAll('th')
            column_headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('th')]                      
            statistics = soup.find("table", {"id" :                     
'"SeasonSplits1_dgSeason" + str(season) + "_ctl00"})'
            tabledata = [td.getText() for td in statistics('td')]                         
            print(tabledata)
```

Comment: First off instead of creating urls dynamically. create a parameters dictionary and feed through `requests.get`. I will write up a solution in a moment.

Comment: I'm relatively new so I don't know much about parameters dictionary but willing to learn.  I will be scraping somewhere around 5,000 websites.

Comment: Wow. That's a nice size project. Check out the requests parameters documentation. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: Yes, I may scale it down a bit but for right now that is what I have - it basically takes a player and grabs their stats against a right handed pitcher and also a left handed pitcher - then it also grabs pitching statistics so there will be a lot of webpages.  Also, that code works just fine for grabbing the website so I appreciate you showing me the parameters dictionary but am more concerned with how to scrape each row of the tables and get them into a list because I cannot solve that part.

Comment: Yes Sorry. I havent coded in about 2 years, So im installing the needed libraries right now. It will take me a little while but I will have a documented solution for you in a couple of hours. Its a nice review project for me.

Comment: That would be amazing.  Thanks so much for your help as I have been struggling for a while with this.

Comment: Yeah scraping can be tricky when starting out, but I find it to be the easiest field in python programming.

Comment: Let me know if this helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be my last attempt. It has every thing you should need. I created a traceback to where the tables, rows and columns are being scraped. This all happens in the function `extract_table()`. follow the traceback markers and don't worry about any other code. Don't let the large file size worry you its mostly documentation and spacing.

#### Traceback marker: `### ... ###`

#### Start at line 95 with traceback marker `### START HERE ###`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests
import urllib


###### GO TO LINE 95 ######


### IGNORE ###
def generate_urls (idList, splitList):
    """ Using and id list and a split list generate a list urls"""
    urls = []
    url = 'http://www.fangraphs.com/statsplits.aspx'

    for id in idList:
        for split in splitList:
            # The parameters used in creating the url
            url_payload = {'split': split, 'playerid': id, 'position': 'OF', 'season': 0}
            # Create the url and store add to the collection of urls
            urls += ['?'.join([url, urllib.urlencode(url_payload)])]
    return urls # Return the list of urls




### IGNORE ###
def extract_player_name (soup):
    """ Extract the player name from the browser title """
    # Browser title contains player name, strip all but name
    player_name = repr(soup.title.text.strip('\r\n\t')) 
    player_name = player_name.split(' \\xbb')[0] # Split on ` »`
    player_name = player_name[2:] # Erase a leading characters from using `repr`
    return player_name



########## FINISH HERE ##########
def extract_table (table_id, soup):
    """ Extract data from a table, return the column headers and the table rows"""

    ### IMPORTANT: THIS CODE IS WHERE ALL THE MAGIC HAPPENS ### 
    # - First: Find lowest level tag of all the data we want (container).
    #
    # - Second: Extract the table column headers, requires minimal mining
    #
    # - Third: Gather a list of tags that represent the tables rows
    #
    # - Fourth: Loop through the list of rows 
    #      A): Mine all columns in the row

    ### IMPORTANT: Get A Reference To The Table ###
    # SCRAPE 1:
    table_tag = soup.find("table", {"id" : 'SeasonSplits1_dgSeason%d_ctl00' % table_id})            

    # SCRAPE 2: 
    columns = [th.text for th in table_tag.findAll('th')]

    # SCRAPE 3: 
    rows_tags = table_tag.tbody.findAll('tr'); # All 'tr' tags in the table `tbody` tag are row tags

    ### IMPORTANT: Cycle Through Rows And Collect Column Data ###
    # SCRAPE 4:
    rows = [] # List of all table rows
    for row_tag in rows_tags:

        ### IMPORTANT: Mine All Columns In This Row || LOWEST LEVEL IN THE MINING OPERATION. ###
        # SCRAPE 4.A
        row = [col.text for col in row_tag.findAll('td')] # `td` represents a column in a row.

        rows.append (row) # Add this row to all the other rows of this table  

    # RETURN: The column header and the rows of this table
    return [columns, rows]



### Look Deeper ###
def extract_player (soup):
    """ Extract player data and store in a list. ['name', [columns, rows], [table2]]"""
    player = [] # A list store data in

    # player name is first in player list
    player.append (extract_player_name (soup))

    # Each table is a list entry
    for season in range(1,4): 
        ### IMPORTANT: No Table Related Data Has Been Mined Yet. START HERE ###
        ###     - Line: 37
        table = extract_table (season, soup) # `season` represents the table id 
        player.append(table) # Add this table(list to the player data list

    # Return the player list    
    return player


##################################################
################## START HERE ####################
##################################################
###
### OBJECTIVE: 
###
### - Follow the trail of important lines that extract the data
###     - Important lines will be marked as the following `### ... ###`
### 
### All this code really needs is a url and the `extract_table()` function.
###
### The `main()` function is where the journey starts
###
##################################################
##################################################



def main ():
    """ The main function is the core program code. """

    # Luckily the pages we will scrape all have the same layout making mining easier.    

    all_players = [] # A place to store all the data

    # Values used to alter the url when making requests to access more player statistics
    idList2 = ['15640', '9256']
    splitList=[0.4,0.2,0.3,0.4]

    # Instead of looping through variables that dont tell a story,
    # lets create a list of urls generated from those variables.
    # This way the code is self-explanatory and is human-readable.
    urls = generate_urls(idList2, splitList) # The creation of the url is not important right now

    # Lets scrape each url
    for url in urls:
        print url

        # First Step: get a web page via http request.
        response = requests.get (url)

        # Second step: use a parsing library to create a parsable object 
        soup = Soup(response.text, "html.parser") # Create a soup object (Once)

        ### IMPORTANT: Parsing Starts and Ends Here ###
        ###     - Line: 75
        # Final Step: Given a soup object, mine player data
        player = extract_player (soup)

        # Add the new entry to the list
        all_players += [player]

    return all_players





# If this script is being run, not imported, run the `main()` function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_players = main ()

    print all_players[0][0] # Player List -> Name
    print all_players[0][1] # Player List -> Table 1
    print all_players[0][2] # Player List -> Table 2
    print all_players[0][3] # Player List -> Table 3

    print all_players[0][3][0]       # Player List -> Table 1 -> Columns
    print all_players[0][3][1]       # Player List -> Table 1 -> All Rows
    print all_players[0][3][1][0]    # Player List -> Table 1 -> All Rows -> Row 1
    print all_players[0][3][1][2]    # Player List -> Table 1 -> All Rows -> Row 2
    print all_players[0][3][1][2][0] # Player List -> Table 1 -> All Rows -> Row 2 -> Colum 1
```

Comment: Note: Python Version is 2.7

Comment: Thanks - it will take me a little time to digest and work through as I want to understand what it is doing - I also code in python 3 as I very recently started Python and that was the newest so I just started learning that one. I would also like to export this data into a spreadsheet and I had written that code but will have to take a look to see if it will work still based on what you gave me or if I need to tweak it.                                     One thing I notice is each table is separate - I would ideally like each row one to be a list(due to the order being important) - any help?

Comment: I'm cleaning up some of the code now. I used `#### TEXT ####` to signify where a function should most likely be used.

Comment: I marked it as answered because obviously you have been very helpful.  I will take a look over the code some more tomorrow and this weekend.  I am slowly processing each step and understanding what it is doing and if any tweaks are necessary.  With all of the extra comments and notes I should be able to figure it out.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Thanks and no problem. Sorry I don't know python 3, good luck with the code barrier. .

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the code, `separated functionality`, used `lists instead of dictionaries` (as requested). `Lines 85+ is output testing (can ignore)`.

I see now that that your making multiple request (4) for the same player to gather more data on them. In the `last answer` I provided, the code `only kept` the `last request` made. Using a list eliminated this problem.

You may want to condense the list so that their is only one entry per player.

- The `core of the program` is on `lines 65-77`
- Everything above `all_player` decleration on line 57 is a function To handle scraping.

## UPDATED: scrape_players.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests


def http_get (id, split):
    """ Make a get request, return the response. """
    # Create url parameters dictinoary
    payload = {'split': split, 'playerid': id, 'position': 'OF', 'season': 0}
    url = 'http://www.fangraphs.com/statsplits.aspx'
    return requests.get(url, params=payload) # Pass payload through `requests.get()`


def extract_player_name (soup):
    """ Extract the player name from the browser title """
    # Browser title contains player name, strip all but name
    player_name = repr(soup.title.text.strip('\r\n\t')) 
    player_name = player_name.split(' \\xbb')[0] # Split on ` »`
    player_name = player_name[2:] # Erase a leading characters from using `repr`
    return player_name


def extract_table (table_id, soup):
    """ Extract data from a table, return the column headers and the table rows"""
    # SCRAPE: Get a table
    table_tag = soup.find("table", {"id" : 'SeasonSplits1_dgSeason%d_ctl00' % table_id})            

    # SCRAPE: Extract table column headers
    columns = [th.text for th in table_tag.findAll('th')]

    rows = [] 
    # SCRAPE: Extract Table Contents
    for row in table_tag.tbody.findAll('tr'):
        rows.append ([col.text for col in row.findAll('td')])  # Gather all columns in the row

    # RETURN: [columns, rows]
    return [columns, rows]


def extract_player (soup):
    """ Extract player data and store in a list. ['name', [columns, rows], [table2]]"""
    player = []

    # player name is first in player list
    player.append (extract_player_name (soup))

    # Each table is a list entry
    for season in range(1,4): 
        player.append(extract_table (season, soup))
    # Return the player list    
    return player





# A list of all players
all_players = [
    #'playername', 
    #[table_columns, table_rows],
    #[table_columns, table_rows],
    #[['Season', 'vs R as R'], [['2015', 'yes'], ['2016', 'no'], ['2017', 'no'],]],
]

# I dont know what these values are. Sorry!
idList2 = ['15640', '9256']
splitList=[0.4,0.2,0.3,0.4]


# Scrape data
for id in idList2:    
    for split in splitList:
        response = http_get (id, split)

        soup = Soup(response.text, "html.parser") # Create a soup object (Once)

        all_players.append (extract_player (soup))
        # or all_players += [scrape_player (soup)]






# Output data
def PrintPlayerAsTable (player, show_name=True):
    if show_name: print player[0] # First entry is the player name
    for table in player[1:]: # All other entries are tables
        PrintTableAsTable(table)

def PrintTableAsTable (table, table_sep='\n'):
    print table_sep
    PrintRowAsTable(table[0]) # The first row in the table is the columns
    for row in table[1]: # The second item in the table is a list of rows
        PrintRowAsTable (row)

def PrintRowAsTable (row=[], prefix='\t'):
    """ Print out the list in a table foramt. """
    print prefix + ''.join([col.ljust(15) for col in row])



# There are 4 entries to every player, one for each request made
PrintPlayerAsTable (all_players[0])
PrintPlayerAsTable (all_players[1], False)
PrintPlayerAsTable (all_players[2], False)
PrintPlayerAsTable (all_players[3], False)


print '\n\nScraped %d player Statistics' % len(all_players) 
for player in all_players:
    print '\t- %s' % player[0]


# 4th player entry
print '\n\n'
print all_players[4][0] # Player name

print '\n'
#print all_players[4][1]        # Table 1
print all_players[4][1][0]     # Table 1 Column Headers
#print all_players[4][1][1]     # Table 1 Rows
print all_players[4][1][1][1]  # Table 1 Rows Row 1
print all_players[4][1][1][2]  # Table 1 Rows Row 2
print all_players[4][1][1][-1] # Table 1 Rows Last Row 

print '\n'
#print all_players[4][2]        # Table 2
print all_players[4][2][0]     # Table 2 Column Headers
#print all_players[4][2][1]     # Table 2 Rows
print all_players[4][2][1][1]  # Table 2 Rows Row 1
print all_players[4][2][1][2]  # Table 2 Rows Row 2
print all_players[4][2][1][-1] # Table 2 Rows Last Row 

print '\nTable 3'
PrintRowAsTable(all_players[4][2][0], '')     # Table 3 Column Headers
PrintRowAsTable(all_players[4][2][1][1], '')  # Table 3 Rows Row 1
PrintRowAsTable(all_players[4][2][1][2], '')  # Table 3 Rows Row 2
PrintRowAsTable(all_players[4][2][1][-1], '') # Table 3 Rows Last Row
```

#### OUTPUT:

Outputs scraped data, so you can see how the `all_players` is structured.

```
Aaron Judge


    Season         vs R as R      G              AB             PA             H              1B             2B             3B             HR             R              RBI            BB             IBB            SO             HBP            SF             SH             GDP            SB             CS             AVG            
    2016           vs R as R      27             69             77             14             8              2              0              4              8              10             6              0              32             1              1              0              2              0              0              .203           
    2017           vs R as R      66             198            231            65             34             10             2              19             37             42             31             3              71             2              0              0              8              3              0              .328           
    Total          vs R as R      93             267            308            79             42             12             2              23             45             52             37             3              103            3              1              0              10             3              0              .296           


    Season         vs R as R      BB%            K%             BB/K           AVG            OBP            SLG            OPS            ISO            BABIP          wRC            wRAA           wOBA           wRC+           
    2016           vs R as R      7.8 %          41.6 %         0.19           .203           .273           .406           .679           .203           .294           7              -1.7           .291           79             
    2017           vs R as R      13.4 %         30.7 %         0.44           .328           .424           .687           1.111          .359           .426           54             26.1           .454           189            
    Total          vs R as R      12.0 %         33.4 %         0.36           .296           .386           .614           1.001          .318           .394           62             24.4           .413           162            


    Season         vs R as R      GB/FB          LD%            GB%            FB%            IFFB%          HR/FB          IFH%           BUH%           Pull%          Cent%          Oppo%          Soft%          Med%           Hard%          Pitches        Balls          Strikes        
    2016           vs R as R      0.74           13.2 %         36.8 %         50.0 %         0.0 %          21.1 %         7.1 %          0.0 %          50.0 %         29.0 %         21.1 %         7.9 %          42.1 %         50.0 %         327            117            210            
    2017           vs R as R      1.14           27.6 %         38.6 %         33.9 %         2.3 %          44.2 %         6.1 %          0.0 %          45.7 %         26.8 %         27.6 %         11.0 %         39.4 %         49.6 %         985            395            590            
    Total          vs R as R      1.02           24.2 %         38.2 %         37.6 %         1.6 %          37.1 %         6.3 %          0.0 %          46.7 %         27.3 %         26.1 %         10.3 %         40.0 %         49.7 %         1312           512            800            


    Season         vs R as L      G              AB             PA             H              1B             2B             3B             HR             R              RBI            BB             IBB            SO             HBP            SF             SH             GDP            SB             CS             AVG            
    2016           vs R as L      3              0              0              0              0              0              0              0              2              0              0              0              0              0              0              0              0              0              1              .000           
    2017           vs R as L      20             0              0              0              0              0              0              0              13             0              0              0              0              0              0              0              0              3              1              .000           
    Total          vs R as L      23             0              0              0              0              0              0              0              15             0              0              0              0              0              0              0              0              3              2              .000           


    Season         vs R as L      BB%            K%             BB/K           AVG            OBP            SLG            OPS            ISO            BABIP          wRC            wRAA           wOBA           wRC+           
    2016           vs R as L      0.0 %          0.0 %          0.00           .000           .000           .000           .000           .000           .000           0              0.0            .000                          
    2017           vs R as L      0.0 %          0.0 %          0.00           .000           .000           .000           .000           .000           .000           0              0.0            .000                          
    Total          vs R as L      0.0 %          0.0 %          0.00           .000           .000           .000           .000           .000           .000           0              0.0            .000                          


    Season         vs R as L      GB/FB          LD%            GB%            FB%            IFFB%          HR/FB          IFH%           BUH%           Pull%          Cent%          Oppo%          Soft%          Med%           Hard%          Pitches        Balls          Strikes        
    2016           vs R as L      0.00           0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %                                                                                                    0              0              0              
    2017           vs R as L      0.00           0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %                                                                                                    0              0              0              
    Total          vs R as L      0.00           0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %                                                                                                    0              0              0              


    Season         vs L as R      G              AB             PA             H              1B             2B             3B             HR             R              RBI            BB             IBB            SO             HBP            SF             SH             GDP            SB             CS             AVG            
    2016           vs L as R      11             15             18             1              1              0              0              0              0              0              3              0              10             0              0              0              0              0              0              .067           
    2017           vs L as R      26             47             61             16             9              1              1              5              9              12             13             0              16             1              0              0              2              0              0              .340           
    Total          vs L as R      37             62             79             17             10             1              1              5              9              12             16             0              26             1              0              0              2              0              0              .274           


    Season         vs L as R      BB%            K%             BB/K           AVG            OBP            SLG            OPS            ISO            BABIP          wRC            wRAA           wOBA           wRC+           
    2016           vs L as R      16.7 %         55.6 %         0.30           .067           .222           .067           .289           .000           .200           0              -2.3           .164           -8             
    2017           vs L as R      21.3 %         26.2 %         0.81           .340           .492           .723           1.215          .383           .423           17             9.1            .496           218            
    Total          vs L as R      20.3 %         32.9 %         0.62           .274           .430           .565           .995           .290           .387           16             6.8            .421           166            


    Season         vs L as R      GB/FB          LD%            GB%            FB%            IFFB%          HR/FB          IFH%           BUH%           Pull%          Cent%          Oppo%          Soft%          Med%           Hard%          Pitches        Balls          Strikes        
    2016           vs L as R      0.33           20.0 %         20.0 %         60.0 %         0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          0.0 %          20.0 %         60.0 %         20.0 %         20.0 %         40.0 %         40.0 %         81             32             49             
    2017           vs L as R      0.73           16.1 %         35.5 %         48.4 %         0.0 %          33.3 %         0.0 %          0.0 %          29.0 %         48.4 %         22.6 %         16.1 %         35.5 %         48.4 %         295            135            160            
    Total          vs L as R      0.67           16.7 %         33.3 %         50.0 %         0.0 %          27.8 %         0.0 %          0.0 %          27.8 %         50.0 %         22.2 %         16.7 %         36.1 %         47.2 %         376            167            209            


    Season         vs R as R      G              AB             PA             H              1B             2B             3B             HR             R              RBI            BB             IBB            SO             HBP            SF             SH             GDP            SB             CS             AVG            
    2016           vs R as R      27             69             77             14             8              2              0              4              8              10             6              0              32             1              1              0              2              0              0              .203           
    2017           vs R as R      66             198            231            65             34             10             2              19             37             42             31             3              71             2              0              0              8              3              0              .328           
    Total          vs R as R      93             267            308            79             42             12             2              23             45             52             37             3              103            3              1              0              10             3              0              .296           


    Season         vs R as R      BB%            K%             BB/K           AVG            OBP            SLG            OPS            ISO            BABIP          wRC            wRAA           wOBA           wRC+           
    2016           vs R as R      7.8 %          41.6 %         0.19           .203           .273           .406           .679           .203           .294           7              -1.7           .291           79             
    2017           vs R as R      13.4 %         30.7 %         0.44           .328           .424           .687           1.111          .359           .426           54             26.1           .454           189            
    Total          vs R as R      12.0 %         33.4 %         0.36           .296           .386           .614           1.001          .318           .394           62             24.4           .413           162            


    Season         vs R as R      GB/FB          LD%            GB%            FB%            IFFB%          HR/FB          IFH%           BUH%           Pull%          Cent%          Oppo%          Soft%          Med%           Hard%          Pitches        Balls          Strikes        
    2016           vs R as R      0.74           13.2 %         36.8 %         50.0 %         0.0 %          21.1 %         7.1 %          0.0 %          50.0 %         29.0 %         21.1 %         7.9 %          42.1 %         50.0 %         327            117            210            
    2017           vs R as R      1.14           27.6 %         38.6 %         33.9 %         2.3 %          44.2 %         6.1 %          0.0 %          45.7 %         26.8 %         27.6 %         11.0 %         39.4 %         49.6 %         985            395            590            
    Total          vs R as R      1.02           24.2 %         38.2 %         37.6 %         1.6 %          37.1 %         6.3 %          0.0 %          46.7 %         27.3 %         26.1 %         10.3 %         40.0 %         49.7 %         1312           512            800            


Scraped 8 player Statistics
    - Aaron Judge
    - Aaron Judge
    - Aaron Judge
    - Aaron Judge
    - A.J. Pollock
    - A.J. Pollock
    - A.J. Pollock
    - A.J. Pollock



A.J. Pollock


[u'Season', u'vs R as R', u'G', u'AB', u'PA', u'H', u'1B', u'2B', u'3B', u'HR', u'R', u'RBI', u'BB', u'IBB', u'SO', u'HBP', u'SF', u'SH', u'GDP', u'SB', u'CS', u'AVG']
[u'2013', u'vs R as R', u'115', u'270', u'295', u'70', u'52', u'12', u'2', u'4', u'25', u'21', u'21', u'1', u'54', u'1', u'0', u'3', u'4', u'3', u'1', u'.259']
[u'2014', u'vs R as R', u'71', u'215', u'232', u'66', u'42', u'17', u'3', u'4', u'21', u'14', u'15', u'0', u'41', u'2', u'0', u'0', u'3', u'7', u'1', u'.307']
[u'Total', u'vs R as R', u'395', u'1120', u'1230', u'330', u'225', u'67', u'13', u'25', u'122', u'102', u'93', u'1', u'199', u'5', u'9', u'3', u'23', u'41', u'6', u'.295']


[u'Season', u'vs R as R', u'BB%', u'K%', u'BB/K', u'AVG', u'OBP', u'SLG', u'OPS', u'ISO', u'BABIP', u'wRC', u'wRAA', u'wOBA', u'wRC+']
[u'2013', u'vs R as R', u'7.1 %', u'18.3 %', u'0.39', u'.259', u'.315', u'.363', u'.678', u'.104', u'.311', u'29', u'-3.0', u'.301', u'84']
[u'2014', u'vs R as R', u'6.5 %', u'17.7 %', u'0.37', u'.307', u'.358', u'.470', u'.828', u'.163', u'.365', u'35', u'9.6', u'.364', u'128']
[u'Total', u'vs R as R', u'7.6 %', u'16.2 %', u'0.47', u'.295', u'.349', u'.445', u'.793', u'.150', u'.337', u'168', u'30.7', u'.345', u'113']

Table 3
Season         vs R as R      BB%            K%             BB/K           AVG            OBP            SLG            OPS            ISO            BABIP          wRC            wRAA           wOBA           wRC+           
2013           vs R as R      7.1 %          18.3 %         0.39           .259           .315           .363           .678           .104           .311           29             -3.0           .301           84             
2014           vs R as R      6.5 %          17.7 %         0.37           .307           .358           .470           .828           .163           .365           35             9.6            .364           128            
Total          vs R as R      7.6 %          16.2 %         0.47           .295           .349           .445           .793           .150           .337           168            30.7           .345           113
```

Comment: Okay - I somewhat understand but still have a lot of questions. Is there anyway I could possibly call you and walk through the code, or is there any way you can just write code showing how to return one row from a table - For instance - grab row 1 from the table on the fangraphs player page?

Comment: i'll see what i can do tonight

Comment: I am working through the code a bit more - I was confused because I didn't see any function calls. I am now going through it closer to understand what it's doing & I see that there are no function calls like I am used to, but rather the functions are parameters in the other functions.  I will continue going through it but if I could learn how to scrape individual rows or say the last 5 rows (-5,-4,-3,-2,-1) or something like that I think it would be helpful as I go to other websites.  Also, the split and id are part of the url that gets scraped - (see hyperlink in text before code at very top)

Comment: I get what your wanting to do, selectively mine certain rows of a specific table. You would take the important chunks of code here to do that. But because the statistics live in an HTML table, I find it easier to mine all the table data. Once you have the complete table, you can deiced which data to keep or remove based on the logic you want. Updating The code one last time with the important parts marked.